# console.log() returns undefined when I specify a function as its argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return-value

I'm trying to make a site for students that will allow them to input javascript, run the code, and test the code against expected outputs.
I'm having a little bit of trouble using the Function() constructor to run the code that I get from the text input space.

A button is pressed to run submitcode()

```
  function submitcode(){
    $(document).find('textarea,:text').each( function(){
      var codewritten = $(this).val();
      console.log(codewritten);
      test(codewritten);
    });
  }
```

the test method is here:

```
  function test(inputcode){
    var passed = inputcode; //code that they wrote
    var args = 'pogchamp'; //this is my input that i want to test their code with
    var f = new Function('a',passed);
    console.log(passed);
    console.log('test');
    console.log(f(args));
  }
```

When I check chrome output, the value of passed shows up properly, as does 'test', while console.log(f(args)); returns undefined.

Here is a sample value of the passed variable, just for reference:

```
   function foo(str){
       return false; //auto-generated
   }
```

Thanks, and sorry (I'm relatively new to javascript)

Comment: Not new Function! only passed(args)! passed is already a function. btw a reference to the function.

Comment: isn't passed a variable containing the value of the parameter supplied to test()?

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your snipped. Does the user defined code return something? Because if not, you get undefined instead of the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Function()` creates a new function with the given contents. You're passing it a function declaration so the resulting function looks like this:

```
function( a ) {
    function foo(str){
        return false; //auto-generated
    }
}
```

...which, when called, returns nothing. (You can confirm this with `console.log(f.toString())`).

To fix it you can use `eval()` instead:

```
eval( "var f = " + passed );
```

To all the inevitable "eval is evil!!" comments: this is one of the rare instances where eval is actually the appropriate choice. `new Function()` is also eval by another name. And, of course, you need *at least* try..catch around it to catch syntax errors in the input.

Comment: just to make sure i understand: eval( "var f = " + passed ); would map var f to the function (as specified in passed). I could then call console.log(f('fooinput')); and it would return something intelligible, right?

Comment: @NelsonLiu Yep! As long as the code you eval'd is intelligible :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `Function()` constructor:

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody);
```

The problem with your code lies with function body. It looks as though for sample your supplied this is what will result:

```
(function( a ) {
    function foo(str) {
        return false;
    }
})( args );
```

Which correctly returns undefined because the outer function does not return anything, even though the inner does.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/UK9aS/)

Per the example given [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), function body should not be a function already unless you're planning to call it inside the outer (new function):

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/UK9aS/1/)

> // Example can be run directly in your JavaScript console
>
> // Create a function that takes two arguments and returns the sum of
>   those arguments var adder = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b");
>
> // Call the function adder(2, 6); // > 8